# ajax doesn't work with php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been trying to use ajax to insert data into my database but it didn't work. So I wrote a code to try a basic call for a php file and it didn't work either:

here is my html code :

```
 <form >
    <h4 class="header-title m-t-0 m-b-30">Cordonnées de facturation</h4>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">code facture</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="code_facture" class="code_facture form-control" placeholder="Ex : 008A00098">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Numéro du dossier</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="code_dossier" class="code_dossier form-control" placeholder="Ex : 008A00098">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">TPS</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="tps" class="tps form-control" placeholder="Ex : 0">
        </div>
    </div>    


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">TVQ</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="tvq" class="tvq form-control" placeholder="Ex : 0">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Référence</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="reference" class="reference form-control" placeholder="Ex : VAR R4055555">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">PNR</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="pnr" class="pnr form-control" placeholder="Ex : M15478LD265">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Date de facturation</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" placeholder="12/12/2012" data-mask="99/99/9999" id="date_facturation" class="date_facturation form-control">
            <span class="font-13 text-muted">jj/mm/aaaa</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" id="addfacturebutton"> ajouter</button>    
    </div>
```

and here is my ajax script

```
 <script>
    $('#addfacturebutton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insertFacture.php',
        data:{
            code_facture:$('input[id=code_facture').val(),
            code_dossier:$('input[id=code_dossier').val(),
            tps:$('input[id=tps').val(),
            tvq:$('input[id=tvq').val(),
            reference:$('input[id=reference').val(),
            pnr:$('input[id=pnr').val(),
            date_facturation:$('input[id=date_facturation').val(),

        },
        success:function(data){

        },
    });
});
</script>
```

so in my php file I tried to write `die('test')`; but inserting into database  didn't work either.
it doesn't call the functions

here is my php file:

```
<?php

  include('functions.php');

   $data = $_POST['code_dossier'];

   die('works');

?>
```

Comment: `input[id=code_facture` is __redundant__ and __incorrect__

Comment: there are too much problem in string syntax of ajax code (didn't closed bracets `[this]`)

Comment: And as __nothing__ happens in a callback you can't tell if something works or not.

Comment: There are so many typo mistake in ajax call.and also success function have nothing to do.

Comment: Your code seems fine. where is your database query ?.
check ajax is working or not . open console .go to network tab .and submit a request. there you see what's the data post and what's the response come.

Comment: `$('input[id=code_facture')` has incorrect syntax, it should just be `$("#code_facture")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to dump `$_POST` of your `insertFacture.php` file? It seems like you do have wrong php filename or something wrong with the `functions.php`

Comment: this should be in comment section.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: @MZaragoza You obviously meant `$_POST` [use backticks(`) instead of single quote(')]

Comment: It's just hard to do it on my phone

Comment: I've got what you said. Sure, I'll apply styling to texts next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not confirm if the js code works or not.

Try this:

Change this line:

```
success:function(data){

}
```

to:

```
success:function(data){
    alert(data)
}
```

And change every occurrence of:

```
').val()
```

to

```
]').val()
```

If there is an alert, then the js is working. And I cannot see anything related to database in your php code.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the lines of code in ajax, you can alternatively add an id attribute on the form tag and then either `serialize()` or use `FormData()`

```
<form id='myFormTag'>
```

Then in ajax, simply call `FormData()` on `submit()`

```
$('#myFormTag').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
  data: new FormData(this),
  //other AJax Stuff

 success:function(data){
  alert(data)
 }

  });

});
```